# How can I see a user data in ssrs?

Tags: ssrs-2012

Question
Let's say we have an SSRS report. It has 5 customers' information. I want to create a report so each customer can see only their data not others. How can we do that in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure or in your dataset query you need a parameter that expects the username or user for filter your information.

In your report, you need to add an internal or hidden parameter that send the userId in your report execution:

[SSRS UserID as parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8zrX.png)